# Storing Graph Databases in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, graph-databases

I have a dataset of 6 million entries. Each entry has one-to-many relationship with other entries. Previously this data has been stored in a Neo4J instance.

Does Google Cloud provide a product that can store Graph Databases? Or is there  a way to adapt an existing Google Cloud Database product to work as a graph databases engine?

I am trying to avoid running a Neo4J instance on a Google compute instance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JanusGraph is an open source graph database solution which can use [Google Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/) as a storage backend; here's a [guide for deploying JanusGraph with Cloud Bigtable on GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-janusgraph-with-bigtable).

Some of the folks from Google even help maintain the project. So that might be close to what you looking for.

Comment: Would i need to install and run JanusGraph on a Google compute instance?

Comment: @QuestMonger — yes, that's correct, you would run JanusGraph on a GCE instance, and configure it to connect to a managed Bigtable instance.

Comment: If you want managed JanusGraph you can use IBM Compose: https://compose.com/databases/janusgraph (disclaimer: I haven't tried it, so this isn't a recommendation).

Comment: @QuestMonger: I added a link to a [deployment solution](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/running-janusgraph-with-bigtable) for running JanusGraph on Google Kubernetes Engine, working with Cloud Bigtable (storage) and Elasticsearch (indexing) backends. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you all for info. I am selecting this as the correct answer since no other solutions have been proposed.